# How would one write the following officially?

Tags: translation

I was wondering how would a contract in Chinese state that:

Utilities (gas, water and electricity) are 200 every month and will be settled with a final settlement at the end of the year.

- EDIT -

So what I have tried so far is: 水, 電, 油費 應該每月支付, 年末

1. I am not sure whether there is a word for utilities that is commonly used. I hear 水電費 more often, but that does not include gas.
2. In English I use the word should more often, but I don't see that being used in contracts.
3. In addition, the last issue is, I don't know how to say a final settlement.

Comment: "Utilities" 在台灣大多用「水電費」一詞，不包括瓦斯。因為冬天我們不提供暖氣。
至於洗澡的熱水，有些用電，有些用瓦斯，所以要另外談。
我們在租房子的時候，會問房東：「水電費怎麼算？熱水呢？」
你的句子大致可以翻成：水、電、瓦斯每個月兩百元，（而且會在）年底結算（清楚）。

Comment: better search for "contract language",google 合同写法，get e.g. https://www.liuxue86.com/hetongfanben/xieyishu/ see esp. 【 liuxue86.com - 租赁合同 】

Comment: 水电气/水电煤（费）are fairly common in mainland China. Btw 油費 means gas bill as in petrol, not gas for cooking or heating.

Answer (score 1):

see e.g. LINE dictionary examples:utilities:水电费都包括吗？ 租金含水电费吗, **gas**: 我去缴纳 **煤气费** every month 每月首日支付租金 settled at end: 每年年底结帐 final settlement date 到期日 suggestion as follows:

每月支付煤气水电费２００美元（？）以年底到期日结帐  (to be settled at end of year settlement date)

added 6/3/19: another term for "gas" 燃气费